# Error in the webpage obtained by using Python's requests's post method

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use Python requests module to do a web form filling and using BeautifulSoup to parse the resulting webpage to get a link in it (which is actually an image link with the image in FITS format) and then saving it.

This is the website to which I am submitting the form:http://tgss.ncra.tifr.res.in/tgss_postage_test.html

My code is as follows:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import shutil

url = "http://tgss.ncra.tifr.res.in/cgi-bin/tgss_postage_test.cgi"
val = { 'raval':'12 00 00.00', 'decval':'-32 00 00.00'}
s1 = r.post(url, data=val)
soup = bs(s1.text,'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'tgss.ncra' in link['href']:
        imgurl = link['href']
        print imgurl
        res = r.get(imgurl, stream=True)
with open('img.fits', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, out_file)
```

For a trial form values, like 'raval':'12 00 00.00', 'decval':'-32 00 00.00' yields a webpage having a link. I cannot share the link to the resulting webpage as it is a general link and one can view the contents only after filling the form as in the previous link.

As seen from the code I am using BeautifulSoup to parse the resulting webpage and get a link to the image.
The problem is the link that I get from my tiny code is not correct. When I write it out, I get a image file (img.fits) of only 14 kb.
If I do the same thing manually I get a correct link and the saved image is then of 124 kb

I am very new to programming and have no knowledge of HTML so it would be helpful to know what is going wrong ? Is it the website that has some problem or my code.

Comment: The link produced by the script is indeed results in a 14kb file; that's all that the server offers you. I don't see anything wrong with your code here, really.

Comment: Looking at the [presumed form itself](http://tgss.ncra.tifr.res.in/tgss_postage_test.html), perhaps you simply need to include the other parameters being posted? You are missing the szval, szunit and fmtval parameters.

Comment: If I did the form filling manually and then saved the 'FITS file' link on resulting webpage then that file is 124 kb. I did try with giving the values but it results in a trace back probably because they are already set in the form.

Comment: Nope, I set the parameters and as expected I get a much larger file.

Answer (score 0):

You omitted several parameters that the [original form](http://tgss.ncra.tifr.res.in/tgss_postage_test.html) sends along; these *are* needed still:

```
val = {
    'raval': '12 00 00.00',
    'decval': '-32 00 00.00',
    'szval': '0.25',
    'szunit': 'deg',
    'fmtval': 'fits'
}
```

With those additional parameters the resulting file is 216000 bytes long:

```
>>> val = { 'raval':'12 00 00.00', 'decval':'-32 00 00.00', 'szval': '0.25', 'szunit': 'deg', 'fmtval': 'fits'}
>>> s1 = r.post(url, data=val)
>>> soup = bs(s1.text,'lxml')
>>> imgurl = soup.select('a[href*=tgss.ncra]')[0]['href']
>>> res = r.get(imgurl, stream=True)
>>> res.headers['content-length']
'216000'
```

You can improve your BeautifulSoup parsing a little by using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select the specific URL:

```
soup = bs(s1.content, 'lxml')  # leave decoding to BS4
fits_links = soup.select('a[href*=tgss.ncra]')
if fits_links:
    imgurl = fits_links[0]['href']
    res = r.get(imgurl, stream=True)
    with open('img.fits', 'wb') as out_file:
        r.raw.decode_content = True  # in case compression was used
        shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, out_file)
```

I've also enabled Content-Encoding compression handling on the raw `urllib3` connection object there; if the service ever enables such compression that'll handle decompression transparently.